# Solving a limit that contains multiple variables

Tags: limits

The question is as follows: Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. Find all the values of $a,b,c,d$ that make $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+ax+b} - \sqrt{x^2+cx+d}=1$.

What I tried doing is multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate, that is $* (\frac{\sqrt{x^2+ax+b} + \sqrt{x^2+cx+d}}{\sqrt{x^2+ax+b} + \sqrt{x^2+cx+d}})$ to simplify the expression and get rid of the square root in the numerator. 
Then, I got $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ax+b-cx-d}{\sqrt{x^2+ax+b} + \sqrt{x^2+cx+d}}=1$.After doing that, I tried multiplying top and bottom by $\frac{1}{x}$ to get 
 $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ax/x+b/x-cx/x-d/x}{\sqrt{x^2/x+ax/x+b/x} + \sqrt{x^2/x+cx/x+d/x}}=1$, which left me with 
$\frac{a -c}{\sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x+c}}=1$. 
But I don't know what to do from this point onward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you multiply the top and bottom by $\frac{1}{x}$, under the square root, your $x$ should become $x^2$:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{ax}{x}+\frac{b}{x}-\frac{cx}{x}-\frac{d}{x}}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{ax}{x^2}+\frac{b}{x^2}} + \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{cx}{x^2}+\frac{d}{x^2}}}=1$$

so that you are left with $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{1}$ in the denominator. The limit is thus:

$$\frac{a-c}{2}=1$$

So we only need $a=c+2$, $b$ and $d$ can be any real numbers.

Comment: Can we also say that $c \in \mathbb{R}$, as well?

Comment: @Bloselink, yes, of course. To write it concisely, the solution is $(a,b,c,d)=(y+2,x,y,z)$, where $x,y,z$ can be any real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be, after factoring out by $ x $ and simplifying,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{a-c+\frac bx-\frac dx}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{c}{x}+\frac{d}{x^2}}}$$

$$=\frac{a-c}{2}$$

The condition you look for is
$$a=c+2$$